# Codeigniter - avoiding duplicate entries for database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need a help for avoid duplication entries on my database table using CodeIgniter.
I have a table called “user_course_tbl” with 3 columns as mentioned below.

1. Id
2. staff_name
3. course_code

I need to enter staff name and course code without duplications.

[image]

As mentioned in table, same person can add more different course codes. But same person couldn’t add same course code more than 1.

Ex: Smith has more different courses for the table. It will be ok. But Ann has same course more than 1. This should be avoiding. should not have same value for staff_name and course_code columns both together.

I wrote coding for the above matter. But I couldn’t understand to validate this matter.

**View**

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Course/insert_courses_for_users');?>
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>User</label>
                            <select id="user" class="form-control" name="user" required>
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <?php
                            if(isset($user))
                            {
                                foreach($user as $cnt)
                                {
                                print "<option value='".$cnt['staff_name']."'>".$cnt['staff_name']."</option>";
                                }
                            } 
                            ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Course Code</label>
                            <select id="CourseCode" class="form-control" name="courscode" onchange="getcoursename(this.value)" required>
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            
                            <?php
                             
                            if(isset($coursecode))
                            {
                                foreach($coursecode as $cnt)
                                {
                                print "<option value='".$cnt['course_code']."'>".$cnt['course_code']."</option>";
                                }
                            } 

                          
                        ?>
                            
                            
                            
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
function insert_courses_for_users()
    {  
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user', 'User', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('courscode', 'Course Code', 'required');
        
        
        $id=$this->input->post('txtid');
        $user=$this->input->post('user');
        $coursecode=$this->input->post('courscode');
        

        $data=$this->Course_model->insert_courses_for_user(array('id'=>$id,'staff_name'=>$user,'course_code'=>$coursecode));
        

        if($data==true)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', "New Course added for user Succesfully"); 
        }else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', "Sorry, New Course added for user is Failed.");
        }

        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

    }
```

**Model**

```
function insert_courses_for_user($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert("user_course_tbl",$data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
        

    }
```

Could you please help to solve this matter?

Answer (score 0):

**(1)Method:-**

**In Controller:-**

When you define the form validation , add a validator for `is_unique`

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('staff_name', 'Staff Name', 'required|is_unique[user_course_tbl.staff_name]');
```

**(2)Method:-**

Search in the database ,the `course_code` & `staff_name` before insertion they exsists or not.

Comment: when I have added "is_unique" to the staff_name column, could I insert same name to staff_name again and again? I need to add different course code to same person, but avoiding same course code for same person.

Comment: @Das use second method.

Comment: how to do it? could you please explain?

Comment: whatever you input is entered is searched in database is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

- **Solution 1**
- $courscode=$this->db->query('select * from user_course_tbl where
  courscode='.$this->input->post('courscode'));

  ```
  if(isset($courscode)  &&  !empty($courscode)) {    $is_unique = 
  '|is_unique[user_course_tbl.courscode]' } else {    $is_unique =  ''
  }

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('courscode', 'Course Code',
  'required|trim|xs0s_clean'.$is_unique);

  $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'The %s is already
  taken, Please use another %s'); // add message for the is_unique

  note :use same for staff name.
  ```

Solution 2:

```
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('courscode', 'Source Code',    'required|is_unique[user_course_tbl.courscode');
```